# GetSessionToken command not found in AWS SDK

Tags: php, session, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, token

I have the following code

```
<?php

require '../aws/aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\Sts\StsClient;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$sts = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => 'key',
    'secret' => 'key',
));

$result = $sts->getSessionToken();

$credentials = $result->get('Credentials');

print_r($credentials);

?>
```

However, it's resulting in this error:

```
Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Common\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Command was not found matching GetSessionToken' in /home/site/public_html/dev/testAWS/core/aws/Guzzle/Service/Client.php:87 Stack trace: #0 /home/site/public_html/dev/testAWS/core/aws/Guzzle/Service/Client.php(76): Guzzle\Service\Client->getCommand('GetSessionToken', Array) #1 /home/site/public_html/dev/testAWS/core/aws/Aws/Common/Client/AbstractClient.php(105): Guzzle\Service\Client->__call('GetSessionToken', Array) #2 /home/site/public_html/dev/testAWS/core/ajax/test2.php(13): Aws\Common\Client\AbstractClient->__call('getSessionToken', Array) #3 /home/site/public_html/dev/testAWS/core/ajax/test2.php(13): Aws\S3\S3Client->getSessionToken() #4 {main} thrown in /home/site/public_html/dev/testAWS/core/aws/Guzzle/Service/Client.php on line 87
```

The issue is with this line:

```
$result = $sts->getSessionToken();
```

I've been following this guide:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AuthUsingTempSessionTokenPHP.html

I don't see any reason for the error to be occurring. Is there any reason for this, or a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing the example up. S3Client::factory() expects a token as a param. You maybe should be using StsClient::factory()?